# Querying pivot attributes in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am creating a basic messaging system and need to query the data on a pivot table. The relevant tables are set up like so:

```
|  conversations  |  messages         |  message_user  |  conversation_user  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  id             |  id               |  message_id    |  conversation_id    |           
|  created_at     |  conversation_id  |  user_id       |  user_id            |
|  updated_at     |  content          |  sender        |                     |
|  deleted_on     |  created_at       |  unread        |                     |
|                 |  updated_at       |  deleted       |                     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Simply, each conversation has users, each user has messages, each message is in a conversation. The `message_user` table is a pivot table, as is the conversaton_user table.

my models are set up like so:

```
class Message extends Eloquent {
    public $touches = ['conversation'];

    public function conversation() {
        return $this->hasOne('Conversation');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot(['sender', 'unread', 'deleted']);
    }

    public function session() {
        return $this->hasOne('UserSession');
    }
}

class Conversation extends Eloquent {

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    public function product() {
        return $this->hasOne('Product');
    }

    public function messages() {
        return $this->hasMany('Message');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {

    ...

    public function conversations() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Conversation');
    }

    public function messages() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Message');
    }

    ...

}
```

When a message gets saved, it updates the message user with a field for each user involved in the conversation:

```
foreach($conversation->users as $user) {
    $message->users()->attach($user->id [
        'sender' => (Auth::user()->id === $user->id),
        'unread' => (Auth::user()->id !== $user->id),
        'deleted' => false,
    ]);
}
```

to get all of a users conversations I do the following:

```
$user = Auth::user();
foreach($user->conversations as $conversation) {
    // get each message from the conversation
    foreach($conversation->messages as $message) {

    }
}
```

My issue is that I need to query the pivot table to find out if the user has deleted the message before deciding whether to show the user the message, Since the deletion is specific to each individual user.

I could do something like this in my conversation model:

```
public function notDeletedMessage() {
    return $this->messages()
                ->join('message_user', 'message_user.message_id', '=', 'messages.id')
                ->where('message_user.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('message_user.deleted', false);
}
```

But it seems a little hacky, is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting Eloquent will provide this functionality for you.

Comment: Soft-deleting will not delete the message for only one user, I would still need to detect if that user had deleted the message and as such, would require the join, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pivot on the collection? http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you can't query the collection based on the pivot table contents.